# SQLAlchemy: How can I get associated value from secondary table?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
class UserAccount:
    __tablename__ = "user_account"
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False)
    account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("accounts.id"), nullable=False)
    role = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)

class User:
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    accounts = db.relationship('Account', secondary="user_account")
    ...

class Account:
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

So here I need to get accounts with appropriate roles:

```
user = User.query.first()
print(user.accounts)
```

How can I do it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Lookup [association proxies](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html). They are a bit more complex than association tables but are best used when you have extra columns such as your "UserAccount.role".

I haven't tested the code, but it would be something like this:

```
class UserAccount:
    __tablename__ = "user_account"
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False)
    account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("accounts.id"), nullable=False)
    role = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)

    user = db.Relationship('User', backref='user_accounts')
    account = db.Relationship('Account', backref='user_accounts')

class User:
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    accounts = association_proxy('user_accounts', 'account')
    ...

class Account:
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    users = association_proxy('user_accounts', 'user')
    ...
```

The equivalent of `user.accounts[0]` is `user.user_accounts[0].account`. By iterating through `user.user_accounts`, it's more verbose, but you can access both `role` and `account`.

Comment: Thank you!
But I can not see any difference.
The result is the same as with the 'secondary' parameter. I still can not refer to the 'role' field.

Comment: Just added a bit of extra info, you need to use `.user_accounts` if you want the role.